# Unauthorized when calling Google GCM

Tags: c#, android, httpwebrequest, unauthorized, google-cloud-messaging

I trying to use Google GCM for sending push notifications. But get a WebException that says that the remote server returns 401 unautorized. I can't foung why it doen't work.

Anyone that knows why it doesn't work?

Here is my code:

```
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

           HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");


            Request.Method = "POST";
            Request.KeepAlive = false;
            
            string postData = "{ 'registration_ids': [ '"+registrationId+"' ], 'data': {'message': '"+message+"'}}";

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            Request.ContentType = "application/json";
            //Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;


            //Request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "GoogleLogin auth=" + AuthString);
            Request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Authorization: key=AIzaSyCEygavdzrNM3pWNPtvaJXpvW66CKnjH_Y");
            //-- Delegate Modeling to Validate Server Certificate --//
           

            //-- Create Stream to Write Byte Array --// 
            Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            //-- Post a Message --//
            WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse();
            HttpStatusCode ResponseCode = ((HttpWebResponse)Response).StatusCode;
            if (ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) || ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden))
            {
                var text = "Unauthorized - need new token";

            }
            else if (!ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
            {
                var text =  "Response from web service isn't OK";
            }

            StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());
            string responseLine = Reader.ReadLine();
            Reader.Close();
```

[image]

Comment: What's the ValidateServerCertificate variable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Daniel - Dude there is an issue with the GCM documentation ! Use Browser key as the authorization key at the place of Server API key . It will work.

Comment: I've tried that, but not sure if it's correct to specify my ip-address on websites. But why did I get a exception on GetResponse and not an reponse code?

Comment: @Daniel - Dude u dont need to ! For browser key is auto generate and you could use this . Secondly i was facing the similar issue which got solved using the browser key as the authorization key.

Comment: I got the same error with the browser key. I added a image to the post above.

Comment: And how do you egt that browser key ?

Comment: dude...you saved my honour...!!!! great solution...!!! Hats off @bhuvin

Comment: where is browser key? It is no longer exist any more in google api console.

Answer (score 10):

OK, i am just shooting in the dark here. Take a look at this line:

```
Request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Authorization: key=AIzaSyCEygavdzrNM3pWNPtvaJXpvW66CKnjH_Y");
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
Request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "key=AIzaSyCEygavdzrNM3pWNPtvaJXpvW66CKnjH_Y");
```

Since you're telling it this is a Authorization header, there's no need to add 'Authorization: ' again, does it?

Also, make sure the string constant 'HttpRequestHeader.Authorization' is 'Authorization'.

Comment: Yes it souinds right. I have changed it and I still got an WebException, but this time it will be 400 Bad Request.

Comment: 400 means your JSON payload cannot be parsed by GCM server. Change your JSON formatting from single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: Hi in my case its showing  Error 401. Can anyone help me please.