# Google Cloud Messaging Server Side Sample in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to write/implement Google Cloud Messaging Server Side Sample in vb.net

Answer (score 1):

It will get you started I think if you struggle with C# ysearch google for c# to vb converter and it will do the job and you will have some code to begin with. And next time please specify your question or put som effort into what you do before you ask.

[Unauthorized when calling Google GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431261/unauthorized-when-calling-google-gcm)

Comment: I got working from [http://www.steveloper.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-and-asp-net/]