# GCM Console shows 0 (zero) requests after a successful

Tags: android, push-notification, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

From my ASP.NET web service and using my GCM Browser API key I can successfully send a GCM Push Notification getting the following success response:

{"multicast_id":4623804699821154941,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1393876717064721%59cd098ff9fd7ecd"}

Two Problems:

1) The Google Developers Console shows 0 (zero) Requests and 0 Errors even after multiple 'Sends' and browser refreshes of the console page. Shouldn't the count change with every GCM Push Notification?

2) My Android device did not receive the push notification.

My code is modeled after: 
[remote server returned an error: (401) unathorized in C# GCM response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407296/remote-server-returned-an-error-401-unathorized-in-c-sharp-gcm-response)

The passed in Android device ID was copied from a successful Android device registration.
My Server (web-service) code is below:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    using System.Net.Security;
    using System.Collections.Specialized;

    public class AndroidGCMPushNotification
    {
        public AndroidGCMPushNotification()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }
        public string SendNotification(string deviceId, string message)
        {
            string BrowserAPIKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";     // GCM Browser Key

            string tickerText = "ticker test GCM";
            string contentTitle = "content title GCM";
            string postData = "{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + deviceId + "\" ], \"data\": {\"tickerText\":\"" + tickerText + "\", \"contentTitle\":\"" + contentTitle + "\", \"message\": \"" + message + "\"}}";

    string sResponseFromServer = SendGCMNotification(BrowserAPIKey, postData);
    return sResponseFromServer;
}

private string SendGCMNotification(string apiKey, string postData, string postDataContentType = "application/json")
{
    String sResponseFromServer = "";
    // from here:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431261/unauthorized-when-calling-google-gcm
    //
    // original:
    // http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339162/Android-push-notification-implementation-using-ASP

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

    //
    //  MESSAGE CONTENT
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    //
    //  CREATE REQUEST
    HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");

    Request.Method = "POST";
    Request.KeepAlive = false;
    Request.ContentType = postDataContentType;
    //Request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", apiKey));
    Request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, String.Format("key={0}", apiKey));
    Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    //Stream dataStream;
    try
    {
        Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();

        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        sResponseFromServer = e.Message;
    }

    //
    //  SEND MESSAGE
    try
    {
        WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse();

        HttpStatusCode ResponseCode = ((HttpWebResponse)Response).StatusCode;

        if (ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) || ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden))
        {
            sResponseFromServer = "Unauthorized - need new token";

        }
        else if (!ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
        {
            sResponseFromServer = "Response from web service isn't OK";
        }

        StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());
        sResponseFromServer = Reader.ReadToEnd();
        Reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        sResponseFromServer = e.Message;
    }
    return sResponseFromServer;
}

public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
                                          object sender,
                                          X509Certificate certificate,
                                          X509Chain chain,
                                          SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

}

On the Android client side I have the following notification-receive code:

```
package com.MichaelResslerFineArt.eclipmessenger;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import com.MichaelResslerFineArt.eclipmessenger.ProfileActivity;
import com.MichaelResslerFineArt.eclipmessenger.R;
import com.MichaelResslerFineArt.eclipmessenger.ProfileActivity.GcmBroadcastReceiver;
import com.MichaelResslerFineArt.eclipmessenger.ProfileActivity.GcmIntentService;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.ComponentName;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ProfileActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    String SENDER_ID = "594966827111";    // GCM Project Number


    public static final String LOG_MSG_TAG = "eClipMessenger";
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context context;

    String regid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        context = getApplicationContext();

        // Check device for Play Services APK.
        GcmApi gcmApi = new GcmApi();
        if (gcmApi.checkPlayServices(this)) {
            // If this check succeeds, proceed with normal processing.
            // Otherwise, prompt user to get valid Play Services APK.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Success checking APK.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(LOG_MSG_TAG, "Success checking APK.");

            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);

            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground();
            }
            else {
                Log.i(LOG_MSG_TAG, "GCM Reg ID: " + regid);
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(LOG_MSG_TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }
    }

    // You need to do the Play Services APK check here too.
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        GcmApi gcmApi = new GcmApi();
        gcmApi.checkPlayServices(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.profile, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service.
     * <p>
     * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
     *
     * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
     *         registration ID.
     */
    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(LOG_MSG_TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
        // app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(LOG_MSG_TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    /**
     * @return Application's {@code SharedPreferences}.
     */
    private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
        return getSharedPreferences(ProfileActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    /**
     * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
     */
    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
     * <p>
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * shared preferences.
     */
    private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                    // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                    // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                    // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
                    // is using accounts.
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                    // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                    // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
                    // message using the 'from' address in the message.

                    // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                    storeRegistrationId(context, regid);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                    // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                    // exponential back-off.
                }
                return msg;
            }

            //@Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                Log.i(LOG_MSG_TAG, msg);
                //mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
            }

        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
    /**
     * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use GCM/HTTP
     * or CCS to send messages to your app. Not needed for this demo since the
     * device sends upstream messages to a server that echoes back the message
     * using the 'from' address in the message.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
        // Your implementation here.
    }       
    /**
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * {@code SharedPreferences}.
     *
     * @param context application's context.
     * @param regId registration ID
     */
    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        Log.i(LOG_MSG_TAG, "entered storeRegistrationId()");
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        Log.i(LOG_MSG_TAG, "retrieved preferences");
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(LOG_MSG_TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }       

    /*
    public void sendGcm(final View view) {
        if (view == findViewById(R.id.button2)) {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    String msg = "";
                    try {
                        Bundle data = new Bundle();
                            data.putString("my_message", "Hello World");
                            data.putString("my_action",
                                    "com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ECHO_NOW");
                            String id = Integer.toString(msgId.incrementAndGet());
                            gcm.send(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", id, data);
                            msg = "Sent message";
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    }
                    return msg;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                    Log.i(LOG_MSG_TAG, msg);
                    //mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
                }
            }.execute(null, null, null);
//        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.textView2)) {
//            mDisplay.setText("");
        }
    }
    */
    public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(LOG_MSG_TAG, "onReceive");

            // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                    GcmIntentService.class.getName());
            // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
            startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
            setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }
    }
    public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
        public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
        private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

        public GcmIntentService() {
            super("GcmIntentService");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
            // in your BroadcastReceiver.
            String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

            if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
                /*
                 * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
                 * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
                 * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
                 * recognize.
                 */
                if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                            extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                    // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                        Log.i(LOG_MSG_TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                                + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(LOG_MSG_TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    // Post notification of received message.
                    sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                    Log.i(LOG_MSG_TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                }
            }
            // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
            GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }

        // Put the message into a notification and post it.
        // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
        // a GCM message.
        private void sendNotification(String msg) {
            Log.i(LOG_MSG_TAG, "sendNotification");

            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class), 0);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

And this separate class for checking the Play Services:

```
package com.MichaelResslerFineArt.eclipmessenger;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

public class GcmApi {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    String SENDER_ID = "594966827111";    // GCM Project Number

    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    public boolean checkPlayServices(ProfileActivity currActivity) {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(currActivity);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, currActivity,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(ProfileActivity.LOG_MSG_TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                Toast.makeText(currActivity, "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                currActivity.finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the Android client side manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.MichaelResslerFineArt.eclipmessenger"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<permission     android:name="com.MichaelResslerFineArt.eclipmessenger.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission     android:name="com.MichaelResslerFineArt.eclipmessenger.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />            

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.MichaelResslerFineArt.eclipmessenger.ProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.MichaelResslerFineArt.eclipmessenger" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you include your android manifest?

Comment: Is `GcmIntentService` located directly in the package `com.MichaelResslerFineArt.eclipmessenger`?

Comment: And do you get anything in the logcat when sending the message?

Comment: Yes, the GcmIntentService is in the ProfileActivity  (main) which is the only activity. The only logcat I get is the Registration ID which I then use in the Server app. I do not get any logcat messages from the IntentService and do not hit any breakpoint in the Intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GcmBroadcastReceiver` and `GcmIntentService` shouldn't be inner classes of your activity class. They should be regular (top level) classes.

When you declare them as `.GcmBroadcastReceiver` and `.GcmIntentService` in your manifest, in means they should be located at `com.MichaelResslerFineArt.eclipmessenger.GcmBroadcastReceiver` and `com.MichaelResslerFineArt.eclipmessenger.GcmIntentService`, but since you implemented them as inner classes, they are actually located in `com.MichaelResslerFineArt.eclipmessenger.ProfileActivity.GcmBroadcastReceiver` and `com.MichaelResslerFineArt.eclipmessenger.ProfileActivity.GcmIntentService`, so they cannot be found when the message reaches your device.

Comment: Thank you very much for the correction. I put the GcmBroadcastReceiver and the GcmIntentService in their own file but it still does not work. The DevConsole still shows Requests=0 (even with a successful return) and my Android app still does not log any receipt of the notification.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the server code (ASP.NET Web Service)? The Google Developers Console still shows Requests=0 even though GCM returns a "success" :  {"multicast_id":8840827068984341411,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1396878214408468%ed0a384ff9fd7ecd"}]}

Comment: @user1987896 The response your server got indicates success, so there is no problem in the server side.

Comment: Then you would think the console would show Requests=1.  I am assuming that the GCM notification is through the Internet connection which for this device is via a Wireless hub (Canadian IP address). This device does NOT have a cellular data plan. It  successfully gets a GCM Device ID which is used by the Server notificaion request.  What can I try next?

Comment: @user1987896 Is it possible your network blocks ports 5228-5230?

Comment: Moving GcmBroadcastReceiver and GcmIntentService outside of the main activity was the main coding error. I finally got notification to work on my Samsung S4 (v4.3 Jelly Bean) which has a cellular data plan but is connected to our WiFi. The notification still does not work on my HTC Inspire (v2.3.5 Gingerbread) which only has WiFi connection. Since both are using WiFi it does not appear to be a network port blocking issue but rather an Android OS version difference or device difference.

Comment: The Google Developers Console still shows Requests=0 even though I successfully received 2 notifications on my Samsung S4.

Comment: @user1987896 `Stats on the Google API Console are not enabled for GCM. You must use the Developer Console.` Are you sure you are looking at the Developer Console stats and not at the Google API Console?

Comment: I am looking at:  https://console.developers.google.com/project Thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: @user1987896 That's the API Console, so you wouldn't see any stats there.

Comment: So what is the URL for the GCM stats?

Comment: It turns out that my company's network does block those ports used for notification. When I took my HTC Inspire (v2.3.5 Gingerbread)  home and tested it worked! I got all of the queued up notifications. My Samsung S4 must have been receiving the notifications at work via the cellular plan rather than the blocked WiFi.

Comment: @user1987896 It's [this url](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/signup/), though I've never tried it. You must register to Google Play and pay $25 in order to login.