# Android GCM server sent but GCM not pushing to device

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am testing GCM on my cell phone. (2.3.6 android).

Manifest file (MainActivity, First and Second activity do not do anything, they are there for some other testing purpose, not interfering with GCM).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.testconnectionapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!--
 Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.

 NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
       where PACKAGE is the application's package name.
-->
<permission
    android:name="com.example.testconnectionapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.testconnectionapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".DemoActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <!--  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter> -->
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".First"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_first" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Second"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SQLiteCrudExample"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

GCMBroadcastReceiver

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}
```

GCMIntentSErvice

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}
public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be
         * extended in the future with new message types, just ignore any message types you're
         * not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
        // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            // This loop represents the service doing some work.
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1)
                        + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            // Post notification of received message.
            sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

// Put the message into a notification and post it.
// This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
// a GCM message.
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.abc_ab_solid_dark_holo)
    .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Now, I can send the message from server as it shows

> Sending 'POST' request to URL :
>   https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send Response Code : 200
>   {"multicast_id":5410443299609525979,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1409160055237618%a13ced80f9fd7ecd"}]}

But after that I do not see the notification getting generated on my phone. What is happening here. What could be the possible reasons for this?

I am connected to the wifi at home, also I have data pack activated on my phone, so even if I disconnet the wifi (not sure why that would impact anyway, but the solution [here suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156995/gcm-console-shows-0-zero-requests-after-a-successful)) but still I am not getting any notification generated.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the wrong category in your receiver (`<category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />`). Change it to `com.example.testconnectionapp`, assuming that's your app's package name.

Comment: stupid me. You must get sick of questions like this.:) Thanks a tonne.

Comment: @Kraken Sometimes it's quicker to answer than to find the duplicate question :)

Comment: Hi, Could you please look into my latest question, if you have any idea about that? Thanks alot though.