# Push Notification Sent From Server But not showing up on any android device

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add push notifications to my android app but it doesn't seem to work. Here's what I am able to do:

1. My client application successfully receives its `registrationId`.
2. My server successfully receives its authentication token.
3. The server sends a message using its authentication token and the device's `registrationId`.
4. When sending a message from the server to the client, I get a successful message response code (e.g.    `id=0:1335303367614556%fd55792500000030` Response code: 200, which per Google's documentation on C2DM should be a successful message).

But nothing shows up on my device, instead whenever I send a push notification, I get errors in my logcat, here they are:

```
08-18 11:17:53.824 11070-11070/example.haris.com.examplelayout E/GcmReceiver: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement 08-18 11:17:53.825 11070-11070/example.haris.com.examplelayout E/GcmReceiver: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found. 08-18 11:17:53.829 11070-11070/example.haris.com.examplelayout E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement 08-18 11:17:53.830 11070-11070/example.haris.com.examplelayout E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
```

Here are my 3 classes which I am using to implement above functionality:

**GCMPushReceiverService.java**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/twLKF.png

**GCMRegistrationIntentService**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfTbm.png

**GCMTokenRefreshListenerService.java**

```
public class GCMTokenRefreshListenerService extends InstanceIDListenerService {
/**
 * When token refresh, start service to get new token
 */
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GCMRegistrationIntentService.class);
    startService(intent);
}
}
```

Here is my main activity code where I am using BroadcastReciever:

```
mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Check type of intent filter
            if(intent.getAction().equals(GCMRegistrationIntentService.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS)){
                //Registration success
                String token = intent.getStringExtra("token");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GCM token:" + token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if(intent.getAction().equals(GCMRegistrationIntentService.REGISTRATION_ERROR)){
                //Registration error
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GCM registration error!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                //Tobe define
            }
        }
    };

    //Check status of Google play service in device
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    if(ConnectionResult.SUCCESS != resultCode) {
        //Check type of error
        if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Google Play Service is not install/enabled in this device!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //So notification
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorNotification(resultCode, getApplicationContext());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This device does not support for Google Play Service!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        //Start service
        Intent itent = new Intent(this, GCMRegistrationIntentService.class);
        startService(itent);
    }
```

And here is my **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="example.haris.com.examplelayout.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="example.haris.com.examplelayout.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Login.MainScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="example.haris.com.examplelayout" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
           <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMPushReceiverService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECIEVE"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".GCMTokenRefreshListenerService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.idd.InstanceID"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".GCMRegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
        </service>
```

**EDIT:**

**Updated Manifest**

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="example.haris.com.examplelayout" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
           <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="example.haris.com.examplelayout.GCMPushReceiverService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECIEVE"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name="example.haris.com.examplelayout.GCMTokenRefreshListenerService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.idd.InstanceID"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="example.haris.com.examplelayout.GCMRegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
        </service>
```

Comment: is onMessageReceived() getting called?

Comment: i think so, how do i confirm it?

Comment: just put a log statement.

Comment: i have, isn't showing anything!!!

Comment: Have you declared your app's package name correctly in your Manifest file? You could have committed the same problem just like in this SO post - [Android GCM server sent but GCM not pushing to device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533655/android-gcm-server-sent-but-gcm-not-pushing-to-device).

Comment: yes i have,i checked, double checked and then triple checked!!

Answer (score 0):

update your manifest file with full package name and sub package

```
 <service android:name="example.haris.com.examplelayout.Utility.GCMPushReceiverService" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECIEVE"></action>
    </intent-filter>
 </service>

<service android:name="example.haris.com.examplelayout.Utility.GCMTokenRefreshListenerService" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.idd.InstanceID"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name="example.haris.com.examplelayout.Utility.GCMRegistrationIntentService"
    android:exported="false">
    </service>
```

EDIT

```
<receiver
    android:name=".ExternalReceiver "
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
       <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Create new class

```
public class ExternalReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String TAG = "ExternalReceiver";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Got push notification inside onReceive: ");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me the package structure screen shot and updated manifest file

Comment: Project Structure Screenshot:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/j5fkS.png

Check My Edit Above As Well.

Comment: the classes are outside utility sub-package, directly under the main package.

Comment: change priority to 10000 and try again

Comment: I souldn't ask this question but can you please Ctrl+click on GCMPushReceiverService in manifest file is it opening GCMPushReceiverService file

Comment: yupp it is opening that

Comment: Strange everything is looking fine,  restart and give it a try.still Error is same RIGHT ??

Comment: yes, I tried the Push notification code alone by making a seperate project just for that and it is working fine!!!

Comment: Giving Error, example.haris.com.examplelayout.GCMPushReceiverService not assignable to android.content.BroadcastReceiver

Comment: update code please create a new class and check are you getting the logs.

Comment: can you please explain it a little bit?

Comment: just create a new BroadCast Receiver and call it from maifest receiver block

Comment: just create a new class inside your package